# Refer VIEW table column as reference

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

Current setup:

I'm using PostgreSQL, node js, and KNEX.

Two tables exist, active(task_active) and inactive(task_inactive), with inactive being partitioned by
hash.
There’s also a view (task) that unifies both tables, and a worker which moves rows from active to inactive when a task completes.

Now, I want to use View id as a foreign key in another table (diff).

[image]
Here is my code

```
import * as Knex from "knex";


export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<any> {
await (knex.schema.createTable("diff", (t) => {
t.increments("id");
t.boolean("numeric_change_value");
t.boolean("string_change_value");
t.integer("report_pair_id")
  .notNullable()
  .references("id")
  .inTable("task")
  .onDelete("CASCADE");
}) as PromiseLike<any>);
}


export async function down(knex: Knex): Promise<any> {
 await knex.schema.dropTable("diff");
}
```

I'm getting the error `task is not a table` and this error is correct because the task is the view. So, is there any way to refer to the view column or any other approach to attach a new table (diff) to the task table? It will be helpful if anyone has a solution using SQL, MY-SQL. I can take those query as a reference for my solution.

Comment: Please do not add irrelevant database tags just to attract more attention. The "SQL" tag is enough to indicate "general SQL". But in general foreign keys can only refer to real tables, never to views. So what you are trying to achieve is not really possible

Comment: Thanks, removed other tags, Now I will work on a different approach for foreign key  reference,

Comment: The SQL tag was fine ;)